# Восстановление базы данных Innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb

В результате 'печальных' событий был удалён каталог с установленной **mysql** и хранившейся внутри БД. Уцелел лишь каталог из `mysql/bin/data/mydbname`, как я полагаю, с данными внутри (судя по весу).

Собственно вопрос: как достать данные их этой папки? 
Там лежат файлы с названиями таблиц и расширениями `.frm` `.ibd` и `db.opt`

Comment: Инструкция по восстановлению тут: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71596/restoring-mysql-tables-from-ibd-frm-and-mysqllogbin-files

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй

> --innodb_force_recovery

Но надо действовать осторожно! Для начало создай резервную копию этих файлов. Подробное руководство на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/125358/) можно найти